# Samsung Galaxy s5 android update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

What is the star icon mean beside the WiFi symbol for the Samsung Galaxy s5. It appeared after I downloaded the new update.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have updated your mobile to lollipop.

If so the star icon basically notifies you that you will be notified of priority interruptions.

Go to sound settings and check for an option called interruptions and then select "Always Interrupt".